# Como mudar Padding ou margin do homeasupindicator

Tags: java, android, padding, margens

[image: tela do aparelho]

Como tirar o espaço entre a seta e o icone do android?

Answer (score 0):

A partir da API 15, o posicionamento desses elementos são codificados de acordo com os recursos do *layout*. Uma alternativa seria usar uma barra de ferramenta personalizada para criar o sua própria navegação e ocultar a interna.

Também para alguns casos, funciona você instanciar o `android.R.id.home` desta forma:

```
ImageView viewHome = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
if (viewHome != null){
   viewHome.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

<sup>**Nota**: A código acima é uma suposta solução [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19600026/2570426) no SOen.</sup>